# What is IOTA trading off giving up Blockchain and adopting DAG?

Tags: tangle

I read a lot of documentation about the pros of DAG over Blockchain. What are the trade-offs of adopting DAG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biggest perceived "downside" of Tangle as opposed to Blockchain is that the cost of decentralization requires PoW in every transaction as opposed to centralizing it with miners.

Blockchain may be compromised by centralized mining activity as we've seen it be manipulated by forks and price pumps based on profitability. IOTA doesn't have this issue, but instead, every transaction must do their own Network PoW, which requires a small but non-zero amount of computing power.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to miners losing their jobs?

I guess probably the higher number of transactions and full nodes you need to achieve stability in the network. Also there are different kind of gametheoretic attacks possible. This has to be further researched by running simulations.